# Annotated SQL variable in facelets generated from entity classes

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans, entity

When generating facelets with CRUD functionality in JSF/JPA in Netbeans 7.3, variables are created in the annotations that specify the SQL statements used to update respective view. The variables are 's', 'f' and 'm'. Where are these variables declared? My assumption was that they would be part of a managed bean with a generous scope but I can't seem to find them.

What are these variables and where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. These 'variables' are so called range variables that are used in JPQL. When auto generated by Netbeans, an annotation like

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m")
```

gets a lower case range variable based on the initial letter of the entity being queried.

These can however be changed to a variable name of one's choice. For more information, read "10.2.3.3. JPQL Range Declarations" here:

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html